# Simplest way to distribute software to customer?

Tags: installation

I have a software business and currently send a zip file with a setup.exe file to the customer. The problem is many don't even know how to unzip the file. If I try to sent the setup.exe file directly they get all kinds of warnings that it could be harmful.

What is the best way to handle this?

1. Get a code signing certificate and have them download the setup.exe directly from my server.
2. Make an msi file.
3. Another method?

I feel like this should be really simple but I can't find much online about an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to use Installshield or NSIS as an alternative solution.

Otherwise, it would be better to create either exe file or msi file and inform your customers that it is okay to launch trusted software whose extension is exe or msi.